# Make the output of Django runserver flush in Git Bash

Tags: python, django, git-bash

When I issue `python manage.py runserver` under Git Bash, only one line of output appears:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
```

The remaining output appear when I either stop the server or make a change in the code:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 01, 2021 - 23:11:21
Django version 3.2.7, using settings 'newserver.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

How do I make it flush right away?

Comment: Do you have blocking code at import time somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I modified `manage.py` using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/107717/2725810). This solved the problem.